# Why does this trigger result in "Invalid Column Name 'CreatedDT' "?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The following SQL creates a trigger without error. When I add a record in SSMS, the trigger fails and displays the following message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'CreatedDT'.

What am I doing wrong ? This is SQL Server 2005 (v9.0.3080). Thanks!

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_XXX_CreatedOn ON dbo.XXX
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.XXX
SET dbo.XXX.CreatedDT = GETDATE()
WHERE dbo.XXX.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Inserted)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me.

I presume that your table can't have a column called `CreatedDT`. Please double check this (including the case of the name as perhaps your collation may be case sensitive)

Instead of having a trigger that sets this on `INSERT` can't you just set a default constraint on that column anyway? This will be more efficient than doing it through a trigger.

**Test Script that works**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XXX
(
Id int,
CreatedDT DATETIME
)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_XXX_CreatedOn ON dbo.XXX
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.XXX
SET dbo.XXX.CreatedDT = GETDATE()
WHERE dbo.XXX.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Inserted)
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.XXX(Id) VALUES(1)

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.XXX
```

Comment: Correct, I could just set the default value. However, this is the simplest example I could come up with to demonstrate the problem encountered. I have the same problem with my update trigger and other triggers with more complicated actions.